# Выбрать 10 верхних объектов

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в ней много записей. Как выбрать из таблицы 10 самых дорогих товаров?

> id | product | price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте вьюшку, и будет вам счастье... Сам запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 10;
```